# Why doesn't the progress bar (Vaadin) update dynamically during the deletion operation from the database?

Tags: java, user-interface, progress-bar, vaadin

**ProfilesDeletionPage** class is responsible for displaying the page where the deletion process takes place. The process involves uploading a file containing the data to be deleted. After the file is uploaded, the data is extracted from the file and stored in a temporary table in the database. The file is uploaded successfully.
Method **deleteMsisdns** which is executed asynchronously is responsible for executing an sql script to delete the data. Method **getDeletedCount** is responsible for counting the deleted data and calculating the progress value **float progress = (float)deletedCount/totalCountToDelete**. This progress value is then passed to the method
processingUpdated, which is responsible for updating the progress bar. However, despite passing the new progress value on each iteration(I can see this from the application logs), the progress bar is not being updated as expected.  What seems to be the issue?

```
public class ProfilesDeletionPage extends AbstractIntfPage {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfilesDeletionPage.class);
    
    static final String[] HEADERS = {"MSISDN"};
    
    Label statusLabel;
    
    int all = 0;
    Long sequenceId;
    Long totalCountToDelete;
    
    Button submitButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    
    File tempFile;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    
    @Autowired
    MicaCommonDaoImpl dao;
    
    public ProfilesDeletionPage() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        boolean btnEnabled = user.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Roles.APPLICATION_ADMIN.name()));
        if (!btnEnabled) {
            showNotification("Only admin is allowed to delete msisdns", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
    
        Upload uploadCSV = new Upload("Upload csv here", null);
        final CsvReceiver receiver = new CsvReceiver();
        uploadCSV.setReceiver(receiver);
        final UploadListener listener = new UploadListener();
        uploadCSV.addFinishedListener(listener);
        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        statusLabel = new Label();
    
        submitButton = new Button("Delete uploaded msisdns");
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        submitButton.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) event -> {
            final AsyncDeletionProcessService deletionService = app.getBean(AsyncDeletionProcessService.class);
            progressBar.setCaption("Processing...");
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            deletionService.deleteMsisdns(sequenceId, user.getId(), user.getLogin());
            deletionService.getDeletedCount(totalCountToDelete, this::processingUpdated, this::processingSucceeded);
        });
    
    
        HorizontalLayout horLay = new HorizontalLayout();
        horLay.setSpacing(true);
        horLay.addComponents(submitButton);
        horLay.setComponentAlignment(submitButton, Alignment.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        layout.addComponents(uploadCSV, statusLabel, progressBar, horLay);
    }
    
    public void processingUpdated(Float progress) {
        log.info("processingUpdated");
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> progressBar.setValue(progress));
    }
    
    public void processingSucceeded() {
        log.info("processingUpdated");
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
            progressBar.setVisible(false);
            Notification.show("Done!");
        });
    }
    
    class CsvReceiver implements Upload.Receiver {
    
        @Override
        public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
            log.info("profiles deletion file has been received");
            all = 0;
            submitButton.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".csv");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fos;
        }
    }
    
    class UploadListener implements Upload.FinishedListener {
    
        @Override
        public void uploadFinished(Upload.FinishedEvent event) {
            log.info("finish upload");
            List<String> msisdnList = Lists.newArrayList();
    
            try {
                log.info("we are before reading the file");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                log.info("we are after reading the file");
    
                //check headers
                if (line == null || !headersAreCorrect(line)){
                    Notification notification = new Notification("Wrong file (wrong csv headers)", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
                    notification.setDelayMsec(4000);
                    notification.setPosition(Position.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                    notification.show(Page.getCurrent());
                    return;
                }
    
                //add msisdns to the list
                log.info(all + " " + line);
                while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    all++;
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    log.info(all + " " + line);
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                        msisdnList.add(line.trim());
                    }
                }
                log.info("msisdnList: " + msisdnList);
                all--;
                reader.close();
    
                sequenceId = dao.insertMsisdnsInTempTable(event.getFilename(), user.getLogin(), "NEW", msisdnList);
                totalCountToDelete = dao.getTotalCountToDelete();
                log.info("sequenceId {}, OK, totalCountToDelete {} ", sequenceId, totalCountToDelete);
                statusLabel.setValue("File loading success.");
                submitButton.setEnabled(true);
    
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private boolean headersAreCorrect(String line) {
        String[] headers = line.split(",");
        return Arrays.equals(HEADERS, headers);
    }

}
```

```
@Service(value = "asyncDeletionProcessService")
public class AsyncDeletionProcessService {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncDeletionProcessService.class);

    @Autowired
    MicaCommonDaoImpl dao;
    
    @Autowired
    CommonDao commonDao;
    
    Long deletedCount = 0L;
    Long remainingCount;
    
    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor asyncDeletionProcessExecutor;
    
    public void deleteMsisdns(Long sequenceId, Long id, String login) {
      log.info("we are in deleteMsisdns method in AsyncDeletionProcessService class");
        Runnable r = () -> {
            int res = dao.deleteMsisdns();
            log.info("res {}", res);
    
            if (res > 0) {
                String text = String.format("sequenceId %d, admin %d %s", sequenceId, id, login);
                log.info(text);
                commonDao.writeLog(new LogMessage(Facility.DELETE_CUSTOMERS, null, text, "new"));
                dao.updateMsisdnBatchToDelete(sequenceId, "NEW", "OK");
            } else {
                log.info("Deletion failed");
            }
        };
        asyncDeletionProcessExecutor.execute(r);
    }
    
    public void getDeletedCount(Long totalCountToDelete, Consumer<Float> progressListener, Runnable succeededListener) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            while(deletedCount < totalCountToDelete) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Query the temporary table to get the count of remaining records
                remainingCount = dao.getRemainingMsisdnCount();
                deletedCount = totalCountToDelete - remainingCount;
                float progress = (float)deletedCount/totalCountToDelete;
                log.info("progress {}", progress);
                progressListener.accept(progress);
                log.info("remainingCount {}, deletedCount {}", remainingCount, deletedCount);
            }
            succeededListener.run();
        };
        asyncDeletionProcessExecutor.execute(r);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to enable push, so the updates are only sent when the next user interaction happens in the browser. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/server-push

Comment: And don't forget to wrap the UI updates in the background thread in a ui.access() lambda

Comment: Hi, André Schild. Thanks for the reply! I added the annotation at the class level - @Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC). But It didn't help. The progress bar is visible but it's not being updated as expected.

Comment: Have you added the ui.access() to the places where you update the UI from another thread?

Comment: @André Schild Do you mean this part?


public void processingUpdated(Float progress) {
        log.info("processingUpdated");
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> progressBar.setValue(progress));
    }

Comment: I have wrapped progressBar.setValue(progress) in  UI.getCurrent().access in processingUpdated method. I pass the progress field to this method

Do I have to add  UI.getCurrent().access somewhere else?

Comment: The issue has been solved! I added this piece of code and It worked.

ui.getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);

Comment: In that case you annotation was not in the correct place. But this is also a way to enable it